# Unable to detect whether Bitbucket started correctly

Tags: bitbucket-server

I am installing bitbucket-4.3.2 on RHEL7.4 but not able to install successfully. May somebody please help me on this?

`[u1120516@ip-X-X-X-X downloads]$ sudo ./atlassian-bitbucket-4.3.2-x64.bin
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
Nov 03, 2017 2:53:37 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$2 run`
`INFO: Created system preferences directory in java.home.`

`This will install Bitbucket 4.3.2 on your computer.`
`OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]`

`Please choose one of the following:
Install a new instance [1, Enter], Upgrade an existing instance [2], Install a new mirror [3], Upgrade an existing mirror [4]`

`Where should Bitbucket be installed?`

`[/opt/atlassian/bitbucket/4.3.2]`

`Default location for Bitbucket home directory

The location for Bitbucket data.
This will be the default location for repositories, plugins, and other data.`

`Ensure that this location is not used by another Bitbucket installation.
[/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket]`

Configure which ports Bitbucket will use.

Bitbucket requires two TCP ports that are not being used by any other
applications.

The HTTP port is where users will access Bitbucket through their browsers.
`The control port is used to start and stop Bitbucket.
HTTP Port Number
[7990]`
`8060
Control Port Number
[8006]`

For a production server we recommend that you run Bitbucket as a
Windows/Linux service because Bitbucket will restart automatically when the
computer restarts.
`Install Bitbucket as a service?
Yes [y, Enter], No [n]`
y

It looks like a Bitbucket service is already installed in the target environment.
The installation will replace any existing services. Do you want to continue?
Yes [y, Enter], No [n]
y

`Please review your Bitbucket installation settings

Installation Directory: /opt/atlassian/bitbucket/4.3.2
Home Directory: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket
HTTP Port: 8060
Control Port: 8006
Install as a service: Yes`

`Install [i, Enter], Exit [e]`
i

`Extracting files ...
  atlassian-bitbucket/static/bower/CodeMirror/mode/elm/elm-min.js`
.......
.....

`Installation of Bitbucket is complete`
`Would you like to launch Bitbucket?`
`Yes [y, Enter], No [n]`
y

`Please wait a few`

`moments while Bitbucket starts up.`

`Launching Bitbucket ...`

`Installation of Bitbucket 4.3.2 is complete`

**The installer was unable to detect whether Bitbucket started correctly
Please consult the**

**/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log' file**

`to verify that Bitbucket started successfully`

`Bitbucket 4.3.2 can be accessed at http://localhost:8060`

`Launch Bitbucket 4.3.2 in browser?`
`Yes [y, Enter], No [n]`
n
Finishing installation ...
`

And, /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log file does not exist on the server even the log directory /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/log/ is also not created.

Comment: What does the file 'atlassian-bitbucket.log' say?

Comment: this file does not exist on the server.. even the log directory is not created.

Comment: I also did find the same question on atlassian community site but no answer..
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Error-quot-The-installer-was-unable-to-detect-whether-Bitbucket/qaq-p/643639